# Is the variance the same as the second moment for queueing theory?

Tags: queueing-theory, variance

In Queueing Theory, is the Second Moment of service time the same as "Variance". I was given a homework question that has 3 parts -

> (a) Service time exponentially distributed with rate $\frac15$,
>
> (b) Deterministic service time equal to $5$,
>
> (c) Service Time of equal probability of $1$ or $9$.

If we do the math, all (a), (b) and (c) have the same average service time. As such, I need to use Variance to differentiate them when using the Pollaczek-Khinchin (P-K formula).

Before doing so, I need to know if Variance is the same as Second Moment.

Any help would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: The Pollaczek-Khinchin formula is valid under the assumption that arrivals to the queue follow a Poisson process. Your question doesn't mention anything about the arrival process...

Comment: @Math1000 Good catch! Yes, the arrival is a Poisson process.

Comment: The Poisson distribution is a discrete probability distribution while the Poisson *process* is a continuous-time stochastic process. Two very different things!

Comment: @Math1000 Thanks for pointing that out. I mistakenly thought they meant the same thing. At least for part (a), the arrival is a Poisson process, but the service time has a negatively exponential distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are defined in queuing theory like in any field (I know or ever heard of) using probabilities. Given a random variable $X$

- the variance is defined as $\mathbb{E}((X-\mathbb{E}(X))^2)$
- the second moment is defined as $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$

Comment: I see. In that case, it doesn't quite make sense to me. For part (c) where the service time is of equal probability of 1 or 9, the Mean would be 1 * 0.5 + 9 * 0.5 = 5, and the Second Moment would be (1^2) * 0.5 + (9^2) * 0.5 = 41. If I applied it to the P-K formula, the total waiting time is 9.1. It seems weird that the total waiting time 9.1 is so close to one of the service times (which is 9). Am I missing something?

Comment: More to the point, I think, is that $$\operatorname{Var}(X) = \mathbb E[X^2] - \mathbb E[X]^2, $$ so we have $\operatorname{Var}(X) = \mathbb E[X^2]$ if and only if $\mathbb E[X]=0$. Service times are generally assumed to be positive so indeed the variance would never be equal to the second moment

Comment: @Math1000 I want to give you a thumbs-up on your comment but can't seem to. Might be due to my low reputation. Anyway, thanks for the comment!